# GDrive response is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, async.js

I am attempting to use the Google Drive REST API v3 to get an id from drive. It returns as `undefined`. Here is my code:

```
            //GETS ID
            async.doWhilst(function (callback) {
                drive.files.list({
                    q: 'trashed = false',
                    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                    spaces: 'drive',
                    pageToken: pageToken
                }, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        // Handle error
                        error(err);
                        callback(err)
                    } else {

                        console.log(res.files);
//THIS IS THE LINE THAT RETURNS undefined ^^^^
                        res.files.forEach(function(file) {
                            console.log('Found file: ', file.name, file.id);
                        });
                        pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
                        callback();
                    }
                });
                }, function () {
                    return !!pageToken;
                }, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        error(err);
                    } else {
                        // All pages fetched
                    }
            });
```

Thank you for any and all help you are able to provide.

Comment: How about modifying from ``res.files`` to ``res.data.files``?

Comment: @Tanaike that worked, thanks

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.